# Google sheets convert month as number to month name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell A2 with datetime like

> 30.11.2020 14:35:54

I need to convert it to MMMM YYYY like

> November 2020

and then rename a sheet with this value

I tried MONTH function in another cell B2:

```
=MONTH(A2)&"."&YEAR(A2)
```

and it returns

> 11.2020

then I used value of B2 in script to rename current sheet

```
function onEdit(e) {
if(e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'B2') return;
    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet()
            s.setName(s.getRange('B2')
                .getValue())
}
```

Another try I did is TO_DATE function, and it looks fine in the cell, but sheet name looks like

> Mon Nov 30 2020 14:35:54 GMT+0300 (East Africa Time)

but I don't know how to convert month number to month name

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try like this:

```
=TEXT(A2; "mmmm yyyy")
```